# How to use OpenCV CUDA in Qt Creator in terms of CMake

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake, cuda

As depicted with the title, I'd like to acquire how to use the `cv::cuda::gpumat`. I have installed the CUDA toolkit. Nonetheless, I don't know how to configure the CMake lists in order to use CUDA in Qt Creator (the build system for my project is CMake rather than qmake).

Comment: If your OS is linux, then you may have a look at the [video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyHbV3XhBoM) related to your situtaiton. and here is an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBMjBKwVaUk&t=27s) also you may check.

Comment: Sorry, My OS is windows! ☺

Answer (score 1):

Never worked with Cuda, but I added OpenCV to my Qt Creator project by adding the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /home/user/opencv_install/lib/cmake/opencv4)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED ) 
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

target_link_libraries(someprojectname PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core)
```

Maybe you have to build Cuda with your CMake in advance.

Comment: hey, man !  thanks for your feedback.Does the means you indicate is that I must build cuda  with the cmakelist that located in the sources file of opencv if I want to use the libaray cv::cuda::gpumat?

Comment: Cmake sets some variables on your system while building libraries AFAIK. So I would build opencv with cuda from source by using same cmake as you use in you qt-project. But this is very vague info.