# Adding glfw to Qt via cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator

I am using `qt6`, `win10`, `mingw`.

I have dowloaded `GLFW 64bit windows binary` from the official site.

I know how to add it via `qmake`, but how could I add it via `cmake`.

`.dll` file location: `linking\GLFW`

`.h` file location: `include\GLFW`

I knwo that there is an integrate qt opengl, but I do not want to use that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68481952/how-to-use-opencv-cuda-in-qt-creator-in-term-of-cmak/68484117#68484117 Edit cmakelists.txt

Answer (score 0):

These are things which I did to make OpenGL work using CMake (This is on a Ubuntu system, it should be similar on Windows):

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

link_libraries(
   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/build_glfw/src/libglfw3.a
   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glew-2.1.0/build/lib/libGLEW.a
   ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} 
   ${GLUT_LIBRARY}
   ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
   ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
)  

include_directories( 
   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glew-2.1.0/include 
   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glfw/include
   ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}  
   ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

This path you have to change according to your dll location:

```
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/build_glfw/src/libglfw3.a
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glew-2.1.0/build/lib/libGLEW.a
```

These variables are provided by CMake:

```
${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
${GLUT_LIBRARY}
${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
```